# xs:string field element in BizTalk schema changes to Uint16

Tags: biztalk, xsd-validation, biztalk-pipelines, biztalk-schemas

I have a schema defined in my BizTalk project, from a JSON instance. The instance key/values are in double quotations so they this means they are strings. But the JSON Schema Wizard set it as `xs:unsignedShort`. I changed it to `xs:string`. When I run my project and some messages contains numbers grater than 65535 this error appears. I get this error from tracked instances from my custom (xml to json) pipeline:
`Reason: Value was either too large or too small for a UInt16.`
I also checked `Schemas` tab in Microsoft BizTalk Administration Console for my schema; the schema view is same as the project in Visual Studio. What is the problem? I got confused..

Comment: Did you restart your host instances of re-deploying the schemas?  Have you checked the GAC to make sure that the version there has been updated?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Hi, Can you help me with the stuff please? I did restart host instances but nothing happened.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I learned about it, so I have some questions. If host instances are restarted, is there a guarantee that GAC renews the contents? I also learned about general versioning in .NET. I haven't used it before. So I should renew the version upon every deployment? And this solves the problem? Do every single artifacts in project development have version specified? How should I interact with GAC and versioning in BizTalk? P.S. I'm a beginner in these stuffs, So this might sound crazy when I ask multiple questions!;) If there is a better place, guide me to ask my questions there. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, restarting the host instances forces it to unload the DLLs it has in memory and to reload them from GAC when they are needed again.   No you don't need to update the Assembly version number each time, if fact we only ever change the File Version as updating the Assembly version would add extra complications (research "biztalk side by side deployment").  No only each project has a Assembly and File version.

Answer (score 0):

as it was already adviced by other users, you should follow the following steps:

1. Stop the host instance of your process.
2. Stop your process from the console (right click on your process and Stop).
3. Deploy your solution on Visual Studio.
4. Come back to the console! Right click on your project and Refresh.
5. Start your process again (right click and start). The host instance will be
   automatically started while you start your process.

Sometimes until you do not stop the host instance and your process and restart them, the console caches the old process version. Step 3 and 4 are optional, but it can be useful to be sure to have deployed the last version of the process.